# Android Create custom SearchView Search action

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

In my application I am using the Action Bar with a custom SearchView in it. I want to use some custom code when the user hits the enter button in the search field. But I cant find a way to catch the moment the user hits the enter button in the SearchView.

Now I tried several ways to capture the search action but I cant seem to find it.

My button is defined like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="-package-.CustomSearchView"
    />
```

With this belongs the CustomSearchView class:

```
public class CustomSearchView extends SearchView implements OnClickListener, android.view.View.OnKeyListener{

    public CustomSearchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setOnSearchClickListener(this);
        this.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
            this.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.setOnKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.d("SEARCH", "Onclick! " + this.getQuery());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d("SEARCH", "Search onkey");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Here you can see that I`ve tried 2 approaches:

1. Catch the onclick event from the submit button. That didnt work
   since it only fired when I clicked on the search icon to open the
   SearchView.
2. Catch keystrokes within the SearchView. That didnt work
   either. Got no response from any key that I pressed there.

Does anyone have a way of making a custom Search action with this SearchView?

UPDATE:

As stated below by PJL: You dont need a custom dialog for overriding this behaviour. The normal SearchView widget will work just fine for this.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Get your search view and add an `OnQueryTextListener`

```
final SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // Do something
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        // Do something
        return true;
    }
};

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
```

By the way my menu layout is as follows;

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll be using this to perform search within a Fragment without launching an Activity. Hoping for the best results :D

Comment: I did that, and I noticed that it is using a default search icon, how can I set my own icons?