# Changing fragment from SearchView submit aka Cascading down the backstack

Tags: android

I'm currently using a `SearchView` object in order to give my application functionality for suggested input.

This widget however, when submitted, uses an `intent-filter` to to initiate your searching. This is great when my application is run on a phone because what I want to do is launch a Search Results `Activity` to display the response. **However** on a tablet I want it to load my search results in a Fragment located in the current `Activity`!

I want my app to be as unified as possible (In terms of crossover between phone/tab) so instead of overwriting the submit behaviour as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938952/android-create-custom-searchview-search-action) I would like a new activity to be started which routes the search term where it needs to go. On a phone to the results Activity, on a tab I would like to pass the searchTerm to the previous Activity.

So I would like to ask - Can you pass information to a previous Activity in the backstack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you having your SearchCatchingActivity acting as a *routing* Activity. It can catch query and pass it to the required Activity (be it dual pane with result fragment or a single pane with single result fragment). Use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` intent flag when routing to the next Activity so that it becomes the default Activity of that instance. Remember to call `finish()` on your routing activity to remove it from the backstack as well.

Comment: Using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP effectively removes the instance of the Activity which is lower in the backstack and re-instantiates it ontop. When used on the directly previous Activity you are effectively calling "Back" in the backstack.

Answer (score 2):

I just set the launch mode of my activity to singleTop and handle the onNewIntent method for this.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

MyActivity.java
(This is obviously over-simplified - you could just have a public method on your existing fragment to pass it the search query.  In the example below I replace it with a brand new fragment.)

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent) {

    MyFragment newFrag = new MyFragment();
    newFrag.setArguments(args);

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // remove previous show list fragment if it exists
    Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myFrag");
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, newFrag, "myFrag");
    ft.commit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My current solution (which is dirty) is to have a public static String in the same Activity which is checked when the `Activity` is resumed, if it is found a search is started using that term and the static variable is cleared out.

```
public class SearchCatchingActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Ensure this activity isn't in the backstack, notify the previous activity in the backstack that it should handle the search onResume()
    DualPaneActivity.searchTerm = getIntent().getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
    finish();

}
```

DualPaneActivity:

```
if (!searchTerm.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
    startSearchThread(searchTerm)
    searchTerm = "";
}
```