# KeyListener on SearchView in Honeycomb ActionBar does not work

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

Here is my code. The onKey() method is never called when typing into the search box. Am I doing something wrong in setting up the listener? I have a breakpoint in the onKey() method, which is how I know it doesn't fire.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.locations_map_menu, menu);

    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar));
    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            return true; // This code never fires
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `return true; // This code never fires` - How do you know that code never fires? Your extract doesn't show any logging.

Comment: I put a breakpoint there and it is never hit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add an `OnQueryTextListener`, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938952/android-create-custom-searchview-search-action/6939735#6939735)

```
final SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() { 
    @Override 
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) { 
        // Do something 
        return true; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) { 
        // Do something 
        return true; 
    } 
}; 

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm not sure why the onKeyListener doesn't work, but thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get a key on serach view
you can use below code

```
    TextView searchText = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
  searchText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            return false;
        }
    });
```